How to end Auth0 session using Reactive Spring Security?
I am trying to logout users in Spring Security. When going to /logout, the app redirects to logout itself with a bodiless 403. In the request, the XSRF-TOKEN and the SESSION token are setted.  Here is the SecurityConfiguration.java file:
package com.emmariescurrena.bookesy.api_gateway.config;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.server.logout.OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.DelegatingServerLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.ServerLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.WebSessionServerLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatchers;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;


@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${okta.oauth2.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${okta.oauth2.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Value("${okta.oauth2.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Autowired
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .authorizeExchange(authz -> authz
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(
                    new AndServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                        CsrfWebFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER,
                        new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                            ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .authorizationRequestResolver(authorizationRequestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository))
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
            );
        return http.build();

    }

    private ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

        var authorizationRequestResolver =
            new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository);
        authorizationRequestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(authorizationRequestCustomizer());

        return authorizationRequestResolver;
    }

    private Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.Builder> authorizationRequestCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer
            .additionalParameters(params -> params.put("audience", audience));
    }
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:8080"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type", "XSRF-TOKEN", "X-XSRF-TOKEN", "Cookie"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

    private DelegatingServerLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(
            new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler(),
            new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler()
    );

    private ServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);

        // Sets the location that the End-User's User Agent will be redirected to
        // after the logout has been performed at the Provider
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseurl}");

        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }

}


application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: user-service
          uri: lb://user-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/users/**
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          okta:
            client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
        provider:
          okta:
            issuer-uri: ${ISSUER_URI}

okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: ${ISSUER_URI}
    client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
    client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
    audience: ${ISSUER_URI}api/v2/

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULT_ZONE}

logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG


Please, specify if more files are needed.
Tried to specify the authorization needed to access /logout, modifying oauth2 scopes, disabling csrf and modifying the logoutSuccessHandler, but nothing worked

Spring Security OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler is for RP-Initiated Logout as defined in the OpenID standard.
Within Auth0, RP-Initiated Logout is an opt-in.
So, if you want to use it, check if you have an end_session_endpoint in your {issuer-uir}/.well-known/openid-configuration, and if it's not there, then enable it.
Otherwise, the Auth0 default logout mechanism is close enough to RP-Initiated Logout for my generic OIDC starter to provide an adapter. If using it, you could replace all your Java conf with a few properties (including the required audience parameter on the authorization request).

Thanks for your response. I checked the {issuer-uir}/.well-known/openid-configuration endpoint and end_session_endpoint is set. The problem is that I don't know hot to use it. I need to use it as the logout url?

No. Spring will set it as Location header of the response to the Post requests to the /logout endpoint of your app with oauth2Login. The frontend will have to follow this URL to perform a second logout (this time from Auth0).

Also, as you have CORS config, I suspect that your frontend is a Single-Page application (Angular, React, Vue, or whatever). In that case, you need Cookie-based CSRF protection for the first logout to be accepted, and letting the browser follow a 302 is likely to cause CORS error on the second request. Read this article to solve both.

Currently, I don't have a frontend defined. Instead, I try to logout accessing directly to the /logout endpoint in the browser. After confirming to logout, it redirects to the /logout again but now with an empty page. When going to the root url, it still shows the credentials, which are updated dinamically and can only be accessed by authnticated users, that I use to verify if the user is logged in.

" I don't have a frontend defined" followed by a collection of UI interactions description: "After confirming to logout", "it still shows the credentials", ...

The /logout endpoint is not defined by myself but by Spring Security as a default confirmation page. That is what I'm trying to say. When going to /, I print the credentials in console.
